# Does anyone have an explanation of the algorithm for calculating weeknumber by Taco Hoekwater?

Tags: calculations

Taco Hoekwater wrote an algorithm in 2006 calculating the [weeknumber](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/misc/calendarweek.tex). 
The algorithm mostly computes the weeknumber correctly, but apparantly misses out for the first 4 days of 2015. Without an explanation of the algorithm there is no way to understand what is wrong.

Does anyone have an explanation of what is going on in this algorithm?

```
\documentclass{article}
%% calendarweek.tex
%% 2006 (C) Taco Hoekwater, public domain
%% Watch out: Dec 29 can be week 1 of the next year; and Jan 3 can be
%% week 53 of the previous year.

\def\Expr#1{\the\numexpr #1\relax}

\def\Modulonumber#1#2{\Expr{#2-((((#2+(#1/2))/#1)-1)*#1)}}
\def\Divisionnumber#1#2{\Expr{(2*#2-#1)/(2*#1)}}

\def\Mod#1#2{\Modulonumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}
\def\Div#1#2{\Divisionnumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}

\def\Jday#1#2#3%
    {\Expr{#1+\Div{((153*(\Expr{#2+(12*(\Div{14-#2}{12}))-3}))+2)}
     {5}+365*(\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})})+
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{4})-
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{100})+
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{400})-32045 }}

\def\cwhlp#1#2#3%
    {\Expr{\Mod {\Mod {\Mod {\Expr
     {\Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}+31741-\Mod{\Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}}{7}}}%
     {146097}}{36524}}{1461}}}

\def\calendarweek#1#2#3%
  {\Expr{\Expr{\Div{\Expr{\Mod{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}-
    \Expr{\Div{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}}{1460}}}{365}+
         \Expr{\Div{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}}{1460}}}}{7} +1}}}

\begin{document}

Week 1-1-2015 = \calendarweek{01}{01}{2015} %% returns 0

Week 2-1-2015 = \calendarweek{02}{01}{2015} %% returns 0

Week 3-1-2015 = \calendarweek{03}{01}{2015} %% returns 0

Week 4-1-2015 = \calendarweek{04}{01}{2015} %% returns 0

Week 5-1-2015 = \calendarweek{05}{01}{2015} %% returns 2


\end{document}
```

Comment: I assume it follows the principles in [Julian Day Calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).

Comment: @Werner: thanks. This seems to be the source. Now just to find out why the algorithm returns zero for 1-1-2015 till 5-1-2015 (european date). will get back to this as soon as I understand what is going on, and what is wrong.

Comment: @Werner: I would like to add a link to [julian date explanation](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~cs1063/projects/Spring2011/Project1/jdn-explanation.html) where a university explains the calculation of julian date really well, including why a constant like 32045 is necessary. Alas, not all constants are explained. Still digging.

Comment: why do you think that is wrong? It looks right to me https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for the pointer to ISO. However, when calculating the weeknumber for 2015 according to the formula on the page you refer to it comes down to 1, not zero. New year for 2015 was on thursday, so the weekday was 4, the ordinal day was 1 so the formula amounts to: (1 - 4 + 10) / 7 = 7/7 = 1. So, the zero is indeed an error. I do think the JD calculation Werner gave is right, because the algorithm uses the same constants. Especially the constant 32045 is important, because it links to the zero date of [julian dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day) from Werners comment.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle About jan. 3rd. Yes, it can be either in week 53 or week 1, but never in week 0. Any year starting new year on thursday start the newyear in week 1 (according to iso).

Comment: @guus sorry I misread this years calendar (I deleted some earlier comments but left the iso link:-)

Comment: Are counts 16 bit or 32 bit?

Answer (score 2):

In [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week), as mentioned in comment, whether a week is the first or 53rd depends on its Thursday. Or equivalently, whether the week has more days on the new year or the old year.

To calculate this in a mathematical manner, one considers the `Round()` function satisfying

- `Round(n+0.4)=n`, and
- `Round(n+0.6)=n+1`.

And then do some calculation like `b := Round(a/7)` and `c := b%53+1`. (Now I want MathJax...)

The problem is that in your `.tex` file, the function `(a,b) |--> Round(b/a)` is implemented as

> ```
> \def\Divisionnumber#1#2{\Expr{(2*#2-#1)/(2*#1)}}
> ```

This `MyRound[(2b-a)/2a] = MyRound[b/a-1/2]` satisfies:

- `\Divisionnumber{7}{14}= 2`
- `\Divisionnumber{7}{ 7}= 1`
- `\Divisionnumber{7}{ 0}=-1`
- `\Divisionnumber{7}{-7}=-2`

And this gives the wrong number.

To come over it, since the numerator, in this case, is always nonnegative, I suggest:

> ```
> \def\Divisionnumber#1#2{\Expr{(2*#2+#1)/(2*#1)-1}}
> ```

Thereore `[(2b+a)/2a]-1 = MyRound[b/a+1/2]-1` satisfies:

- `\Divisionnumber{7}{14}= 2`
- `\Divisionnumber{7}{ 7}= 1`
- `\Divisionnumber{7}{ 0}= 0`
- `\Divisionnumber{7}{-7}=-2`

---

Some test code...
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\Expr#1{\the\numexpr #1\relax}
\def\Modulonumber#1#2{\Expr{#2-((((#2+(#1/2))/#1)-1)*#1)}}
\def\Divisionnumber#1#2{\Expr{(2*#2-#1)/(2*#1)}}
\def\Mod#1#2{\Modulonumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}
\def\Div#1#2{\Divisionnumber{\Expr{#2}}{\Expr{#1}}}
\def\Jday#1#2#3%
    {\Expr{#1+\Div{((153*(\Expr{#2+(12*(\Div{14-#2}{12}))-3}))+2)}
     {5}+365*(\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})})+
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{4})-
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{100})+
      (\Div{\Expr{#3+4800-(\Div{14-#2}{12})}}{400})-32045 }}
\def\cwhlp#1#2#3%  H = (\J+31741-\J%7)%146097%36524%1461
    {\Expr{\Mod {\Mod {\Mod {\Expr
     {\Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}+31741-\Mod{\Jday{#1}{#2}{#3}}{7}}}%
     {146097}}{36524}}{1461}}}
\def\calendarweek#1#2#3%  W = [(H-H/1460)%365+H/1460]/7+1
  {\Expr{\Expr{\Div{\Expr{\Mod{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}-
    \Expr{\Div{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}}{1460}}}{365}+
         \Expr{\Div{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}}{1460}}}}{7} +1}}}
\def\temp#1#2#3{
    \def\a{\Expr{\Div{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}}{1460}}} % a = H/1460
    \def\b{\Expr{\cwhlp{#1}{#2}{#3}-\a}}          % b = H-a
    \def\c{\Expr{\Mod{\b}{365}}}                  % c = b%365
    \def\d{\Expr{\c+\a}}                          % d = c+a
    \def\e{\Expr{\Div{\d}{7}}}                    % e = d/7
    \def\f{\Expr{\e+1}}                           % f = e+1
    \a\ \b\ \c\ \d\ \e\ \f
}

\usepackage{pgfkeys,pgfcalendar}%\usepackage{tikz}\usetikzlibrary{calendar}
\newcount\jcount
\newcount\wcount
\def\pgfjday#1#2#3{%
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{#3-#2-#1}{\jcount}%
    \the\jcount
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
2015-1-1&\pgfjday11{2015}&\Jday11{2015}&\cwhlp11{2015}&\temp11{2015}&\calendarweek11{2015} \\
2015-1-2&\pgfjday21{2015}&\Jday21{2015}&\cwhlp21{2015}&\temp21{2015}&\calendarweek21{2015} \\
2015-1-3&\pgfjday31{2015}&\Jday31{2015}&\cwhlp31{2015}&\temp31{2015}&\calendarweek31{2015} \\
2015-1-4&\pgfjday41{2015}&\Jday41{2015}&\cwhlp41{2015}&\temp41{2015}&\calendarweek41{2015} \\
2015-1-5&\pgfjday51{2015}&\Jday51{2015}&\cwhlp51{2015}&\temp51{2015}&\calendarweek51{2015} \\
\end{tabular}
\par\bigskip
\underline{\Divisionnumber{7}{14}}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{13}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{12}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{11}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{10}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 9}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 8}
\underline{\Divisionnumber{7}{ 7}}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 6}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 5}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 4}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 3}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 2}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 1}
\underline{\Divisionnumber{7}{ 0}}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-1}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-2}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-3}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-4}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-5}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-6}
\underline{\Divisionnumber{7}{-7}}

\bigskip % % % % % % % % % % % % % % % 

\def\Divisionnumber#1#2{\Expr{(2*#2+#1)/(2*#1)-1}}
\begin{tabular}{lllllllll}
2015-1-1&\pgfjday11{2015}&\Jday11{2015}&\cwhlp11{2015}&\temp11{2015}&\calendarweek11{2015} \\
2015-1-2&\pgfjday21{2015}&\Jday21{2015}&\cwhlp21{2015}&\temp21{2015}&\calendarweek21{2015} \\
2015-1-3&\pgfjday31{2015}&\Jday31{2015}&\cwhlp31{2015}&\temp31{2015}&\calendarweek31{2015} \\
2015-1-4&\pgfjday41{2015}&\Jday41{2015}&\cwhlp41{2015}&\temp41{2015}&\calendarweek41{2015} \\
2015-1-5&\pgfjday51{2015}&\Jday51{2015}&\cwhlp51{2015}&\temp51{2015}&\calendarweek51{2015} \\
\end{tabular}
\par\bigskip
\underline{\Divisionnumber{7}{14}}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{13}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{12}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{11}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{10}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 9}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 8}
\underline{\Divisionnumber{7}{ 7}}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 6}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 5}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 4}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 3}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 2}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{ 1}
\underline{\Divisionnumber{7}{ 0}}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-1}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-2}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-3}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-4}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-5}
           \Divisionnumber{7}{-6}
\underline{\Divisionnumber{7}{-7}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Thank you. This indeed explains why the error is occurring and hands me a correction. Thank you very much for this solution.